# In what scenario could my function not work as intended?

Tags: python, list

I'm doing a project on the game Battleship and one of the function has stumped me. Description of the function is:

> The first parameter is a square potential fleet grid, the second and
>   third parameters are the row and column index of the cell containing
>   the top/left corner of the ship, the fourth parameter is a character
>   representing a ship, and the fifth parameter is the size of the ship.
>   This function returns True iff the ship appears with the correct size,
>   completely in a row or a completely in a column at the given starting
>   cell.

My code:

```
def has_ship(fleet_grid, row, column, ship_char, ship_size):       
    row, column = row - 1, column - 1

    ship_char_in_grid = check_specified_character(fleet_grid, ship_char)             
    ship_list = []

    for size in range(ship_size):
        ship_list.append(ship_char)

    horizontal_row = fleet_grid[row]                                        
    horizontal_ship = horizontal_row[column : column + ship_size]            

    vertical_column = fleet_grid[row: row + ship_size]        
    vertical_ship = []                                 

    for row_of_interest in vertical_column:                         
        vertical_ship.append(row_of_interest[column])               

    return ship_char_in_grid == ship_size and ship_size \
           (vertical_ship == ship_list or horizontal_ship == ship_list)
```

`check_specified_character` is seeing how many times the specified character appears in the whole grid.

What I'm basically doing is:

- appending the ship character ship_size times to a list(1)
- for a horizontal ship, isolate the specified row, append from the starting character (specified by column) up to ship_size characters after into another list(2)
- for a vertical ship, append ALL the ROWS from the row that the ship starts up to ship_size rows into a list. Then in that list, append the char at index column from each row into another list(3)
- Then I compare list(1) with list(2) and list(3). The function will only return True if:
- list2 or list3 matches list1 and there are the same number of characters in that grid as specified by ship_size

I've racked my brain of so many scenarios and they all worked out as expected. I don't see how my functions barely passed the checker, so any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

I also felt intuitively that there's a simpler way to do this, and I've tried to think of a way to do it, too, but couldn't. Maybe I'm too stuck with the current method. Any pointers to a possible simpler solution would be great.

Answer (score 0):

1) Wasn't numpy allowed? All your column mangling isn't needed in that case as you have vertical slices.

2) Also you could iterate the grid as a matrix, ie:

```
has_ship=True
for i in range(ship_size):
  if (grid[row+i][col] != ship_char) and (grid[row][col+i] != ship_char) :
     has_ship=False
     break
```